# How to build Splash Screens in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, splash-screen, mern

I am building this website and have hosted it on the heroku free tier therefore takes a minute there before starting up.I feel this is rather slow and would probably be wise if i had something like a splash screen like you would see when you go to the twitter or instagram websites where it displays a logo first instead of just a blank screen before the website loads up.

Would anybody know how to do this in React? Please provide me the code on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is not that the react app takes time to load, but the free heroku dyno itself goes offline if it idle for a certain while.

You can make use of some hacks like https://www.pingdom.com/, where you need to make a request to your app every x interval to avoid it from going to sleep.

Note: This will impact your free dyno hours.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest and, maybe, best way would be to do this through the `React Context API`. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-noyce-pqm9b?file=/src/App.js) is a Codesandbox example of how it can be done using the `React Context API`.

Answer (score -1):

So first what your talking about is preloader, not splash screens,

splash screens are used for mobile applications, while preloader, or loading screens are used for web applications

I could drop some codes on how to achieve that

Comment: Sure, drop the  code. Most of the examples i have seen  now are using the timeout method, but i want is to show the preloader before data is fetched from an api and then show the actual website when fully loaded

Answer (score -2):

So first what your talking about is preloader, not splash screens,

splash screens are used for mobile applications, while preloader, or loading screens are used for web applications

I would drop some codes on how to achieve that, do i get what you need right?

Comment: This is for `React Native`